# Hölder continuity and sublinear growth

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove an equivalence between Hölder continuous function and function with a sublinear bound. That is: let $w\in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then are equivalent:

a) $w\in C^{0,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, with $\alpha\in[0,1)$, i.e. there exists $C>0$ s.t. ${|w(x)-w(y)|}\le C{|x-y|^\alpha}$ $\forall x,y$;

b) there exists $C>0$ such that $|w(x)|\le C(1+|x|^\alpha)$, for every $x$.

I prove that a) implies b): taking $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $|x_0|=1$ we can estimate
$$|w(x)|\le|w(x)-w(x_0)|+|w(x_0)|\le|x-x_0|^\alpha+|w(x_0)|\le|1+|x||^\alpha+c\le C(1+|x|^\alpha).$$

I need an hint to the other implication, thanks you!

Comment: b) can't imply a) as stated. The issue is that a) implies some local regularity of $w$ that b) is not introducing. For example $w(x)=\min(|x|^\beta, 1)$ satisfies b) for any $\alpha\geq0$, but a) only for $\alpha\leq \beta$.

Comment: Thanks @Jose27! This happen because in the example $w$ is not $C^1$. If I add the hypothesis $w\in C^1$  do the result change? Maybe yes, $C^1$ implies locally $C^{0,\alpha}$ and for big value we have a sublinear bound of the growth rate of $w$. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure if that'll solve the issues. Are the constants allowed to depend on $w$? (Notice that already in a) implies b), your constant $c$ depends on $w$).

Comment: I think so, I see no other way